# Crop off Parts of the Image that does not include the Face

Tags: c#, face-detection, biometrics

I have detected the Face in an Image(Only 1 Person) and have the coordinates of the Face Rectangle.

[image]

Since the image can be of any size,I need only the part of the image that is important(head.shoulders).What intent to do is extend the bounds of the detected rectangle by some factor so that the important parts are included.
Is this the right approach?

**Update:**

I have tried this .. but its not giving the correct result.Note that i have changed 1.7 to 2 since it only takes integer arguments.And Top and Left are readonly properties.

```
foreach (Rectangle f in objects)
{
    int x, y;
    x = f.Top - (f.Height / 8);
    y = f.Left - (f.Width / 2);

    Rectangle myrect = new Rectangle(x, y, f.Width * 2, f.Height * 2);

    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, myrect);
}
```

***Detected Face Rectangle***

```
Top----->62
Right----->470
Left----->217
Bottom----->315
```

---

***Extended Rectangle as per answer***

```
Top----->91
Right----->537
Left----->31
Bottom----->597
```

Extended rectangle

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34461393/3902603) as off-topic, I will write my correct answer here:*

---

As I am not completely familiar with [`Emgu CV`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), I would have the following approaches:

1. As Emgu CV is open-source, you could spend restless nights and change the code inside the libraries and recompile them etc.

or *(my preferable approach)*:

2. You think about it biologically, meaning:

   You know the position and size of your face rectangle. If you also know body proporions, you can calculate the estimated width of the shoulders and there vertical offset (relative to the face's center).

---

**More details for the biological approach:**

Imagine *fig. №1* begin true, and imagine that you have the following image and face rectangle:

```
Bitmap
  | .Width == 100
  | .Height == 160

Face // type: System.Drawing.Rectangle
  | .Top == 20
  | .Left == 50
  | .Width == 60
  | .Height == 60
```

then, according to the provided image, the new Rectangle should be:

```
f := Face // face rectangle

Face_and_Shoulder
  | .Top = f.Top - (f.Height / 8)
  | .Left = f.Left - (f.Width / 2)
  | .Width = f.Width * 2
  | .Height = f.Height * 1.7
```

which would result in the following values:

```
Face_and_Shoulder
  | .Top == 12.5
  | .Left == 20
  | .Width == 120
  | .Height == 102
```

The resulted rectangle (`Face_and_Shoulder`) should include the shoulder and hair etc. when drawing it over your image.

This method has however a minor drawback: It will not work, if the face is rotated by a certain number of degrees (I believe more than 5..10°).

---

To calculated the respective rectangle, I would advise you to use this code *(you seem to have confused `X` and `Y` in your code sample)*:

```
foreach (Rectangle f in objects)
{
    float x = f.Left - (f.Width / 2f);
    float y = f.Top - (f.Height / 8f);

    Rectangle myrect = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, f.Width * 2, (int)(f.Height * 1.3));

    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, myrect);
}
```

---

[image: fig. №1]

**fig. №1** *(source: http://www.idrawdigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/prop_var.gif)*

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by .Top and .Left

Comment: @techno: Your rectangle structure should have the properties { Top, Left, Width, Height } and the the 'dot' accesses the different properties

Comment: @techno: I have seen your update, and I will continue to search for solutions. However, I have to visit my family (_christmas_), so you will probably have to wait until this evening...

Comment: @techno: Thank you. Merry Christmas to you, too :) You said, that my method did not return the correct result - in which way?

Comment: sorry for the late reply.Was busy with Christmas and other stuff.Have you seen the code i have posted.It returns a wrong rectangle.

Comment: @techno: No problem :) I have seen your code, but I do not see, in which way it is wrong... Is it to large or to thin or at the wrong position? Maybe you could upload a second image in your post update, so that we know, in which way it is wrong :)

Comment: Please see my update.I dont know if my math is right.Im using the X and Y coordinates

Comment: @techno: I will recalculate everything and notify you later when I found a good result :)

Comment: @techno: how big is your total image (in px)?

Comment: This is the image http://cdn2.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/675x380/2014/11/leonardo_dicaprio.jpg Its 675X380

Comment: @techno: I edited my answer and added a code sample :) ... maybe it will work now.... *notice the `1.3` inside the integer multiplication*

Comment: I keep getting --> Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) .Should i convert it

Comment: @techno: I have forgotten about float literals. Change this here: `... 2.0` or `... 8.0` to: `... 2f` or `... 8f` (I also editd my answer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99187/discussion-between-techno-and-unknown6656).

Comment: Sorry for the accepting the answer late.I had already upvoted it.I had another doubt.How do you suggest to implement a Custom Sized Crop?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a second bitmap and draw the first one into the second one as follows:

```
Bitmap source = Image.FromFile("/my/path/to/myimage.png") as Bitmap;

Rectangle facerectangle = /* your face detection logic */;
Bitmap target = new Bitmap(facerectangle.Width, facerectangle.Height);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
{
    g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height),
                facerectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

The code should be rather easy to understand :)

You first load your bitmap `source`, then create your rectangle using your face recognition logic and create the bitmap `target`, in which you draw the first segment using GDI+'s [`DrawImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I dont think you understand my question.I can crop of the detected face easily.What i need is a logic to extend the detected rectangle properly so that it includes the face and shoulders.Currently the rectangle only has the face in it.

Comment: @techno: Oh, I am so sorry, Sir. I will search for a solution and edit my response appropriately.

Comment: Hey Man.Don't call me sir :) .Thanks for your help.

Comment: @techno: OK ^^. Which code/library are you using for your face recognition?